# How to serialize specific properties in graph model using newtonsoft.json?

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I am trying to serialize model graph using **newtonsoft.json**, and I know that using ignore attribute or using custom ContractResolver I can ignore specific properties from being serialized?

Here's the custom ContractResolver I am using to ignore properties:

```
public class PropertyIgnoreSerializerContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, HashSet<string>> _ignores;

    public PropertyIgnoreSerializerContractResolver()
    {
        _ignores = new Dictionary<Type, HashSet<string>>();
    }

    public void IgnoreProperty(Type type, params string[] jsonPropertyNames)
    {
        if (!_ignores.ContainsKey(type))
            _ignores[type] = new HashSet<string>();

        foreach (var prop in jsonPropertyNames)
            _ignores[type].Add(prop);
    }

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

        if (IsIgnored(property.DeclaringType, property.PropertyName))
            property.ShouldSerialize = i => false;

        return property;
    }

    private bool IsIgnored(Type type, string jsonPropertyName)
    {
        if (!_ignores.ContainsKey(type))
            return false;

        return _ignores[type].Contains(jsonPropertyName);
    }
}
```

But in my case I need to include specific properties inside the graph model to be serialized rather than exclude a lot of properties inside that graph?

Is there any way to configure it to serialize specific properties?

Comment: Just reverse the logic in your resolver such that it ignores every property except the ones you specifically want to include.  So it becomes an `IncludePropertyResolver` instead of an `IgnorePropertyResolver`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified **PropertyIgnoreSerializerContractResolver** a little bit to reverse the logic to include properties rather than ignoring them.

First of all imagine we have these classes:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Person Teacher { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime? BOD { get; set; }

    public decimal Salary { get; set; }
}
```

Serializing class and my custom ContractResolver to include properties to be serialized they look like this:

```
 public static class SerilizationExtensions
{
    public static IContractResolver contractResolver { get; set; }

    public static string ToJson(this object obj, IContractResolver contractResolver=null)
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, new JsonSerializerSettings()
        {
            PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All,
            ContractResolver =contractResolver==null? new PropertyIgnoreSerializerContractResolver():contractResolver
        });
    }
}

public class PropertyIncludeSerializerContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, HashSet<string>> _includedProperties;


    public PropertyIncludeSerializerContractResolver()
    {
        _includedProperties = new Dictionary<Type, HashSet<string>>();
    }

    public void IncludeProperty(Type type, params string[] jsonPropertyNames)
    {
        if (!_includedProperties.ContainsKey(type))
            _includedProperties[type] = new HashSet<string>();

        foreach (var prop in jsonPropertyNames)
            _includedProperties[type].Add(prop);
    }

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

        if (IsIncluded(property.DeclaringType, property.PropertyName) || property.PropertyType.IsValueType || property.PropertyType==typeof(string))
            property.ShouldSerialize = i => true;
        else
            property.ShouldSerialize = i => false;

        return property;
    }

    private bool IsIncluded(Type type, string jsonPropertyName)
    {
        if (!_includedProperties.ContainsKey(type))
            return false;

        return _includedProperties[type].Contains(jsonPropertyName);
    }
}
```

Inside Main method :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var student = new Student
        {
            Id=1,
            Name="Simple Code",
            Courses=new List<Course> {
                new Course{ Id=1, Name="history", Teacher=new Person{Id=1,Name="James",BOD=DateTime.UtcNow,Salary=1000.50M } },
                new Course{ Id=2, Name="Math", Teacher=new Person{Id=2,Name="David",BOD=DateTime.UtcNow,Salary=6000.50M } }
            }
        };

        var jsonResolver = new PropertyIncludeSerializerContractResolver();

        jsonResolver.IncludeProperty(typeof(Student), "Courses");
        // if you want Teacher property to get serialized uncomment this code
        //jsonResolver.IncludeProperty(typeof(Course), "Teacher");
        var jsonStr = student.ToJson(jsonResolver);
        Console.WriteLine(jsonStr);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

So here **PropertyIncludeSerializerContractResolver** will ignore all reference types which are not specified to be serialized.

I hope my code will help others.